# Ubuntu 11.10 - How do you uninstall Ruby 1.8.7 and install Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Does anyone know how to properly uninstall Ruby 1.8.7 and install Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 11.10?

I have thoroughly searched and none of the tutorials I've found have worked.

Also, I spent hours... days... months... trying to get RVM to work and it just is a pain to use. Additionally, I will have little use for the older version.

Comment: This really doesn't belong here, maybe http://askubuntu.com/ would be a better fit.

Comment: Is this a request for help installing RVM in disguise, or a question about upgrading your Ruby? The first we can help with, because RVM is a common tool in the Ruby world, and if so the question needs to be completely rewritten. The second is off-topic for StackOverflow as @vdbuilder says.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ubuntu package manager


Answer (score 1):

Best option is use RVM to switch different versions of Ruby(without removing older one).
In my opinion RVM is simple to install and use.

**To install RVM follow the steps in** http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/21/set-up-an-ubuntu-local-development-machine-for-ruby-on-rails/.

https://rvm.io is the good guide to learn more.

Comment: I've been trying to get RVM to work but have been running into issue after issue.

Answer (score 1):

This answer-

https://askubuntu.com/questions/91693/how-do-you-uninstall-ruby-1-8-7-and-install-ruby-1-9-2

helped me. I wanted to use ruby 1.9.3 in a ubunutu box that had 1.8.7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Install ruby-1.9.1

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

Remove ruby-1.8

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby1.8-full
```

I'm not sure if there is alternatives tracking for ruby. If not, consider linking all the `ruby1.9.1` binaries to `ruby` for convenience.